# CMake is not able to link to vcpkg library

Tags: c++, cmake, itk, vcpkg

I installed a new library in vcpkg, i.e, `ITK` and now I am trying to compile a very first code example available in its guide, I installed it via vcpkg so I skipped the installation part(provided in that guide) and immediately created a new cmake project in visual studio.

```
+ ItkProjects
    - ItkProjects
        - main.cpp
        - CMakeLists.txt  #1
    - CMakeLists.txt   #2
```

#### CMakeLists.txt  #2

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project ("ItkProjects")

# Include sub-projects.
add_subdirectory ("ItkProjects")
```

#### CMakeLists.txt #1

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

find_package(ITK CONFIG REQUIRED)

include_directories(${ITK_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable (ItkProjects "main.cpp")

target_link_libraries(ItkProjects ${ITK_LIBRARIES})
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include "itkImage.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    using ImageType = itk::Image<unsigned char, 3>;

    ImageType::Pointer image = ImageType::New();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

CMake configured and generated with no errors but when compiling I end up with this error:

> ninja : error : '/lib/double-conversion.lib', needed by
>   'ItkProjects/ItkProjects.exe', missing and no known rule to make it

I am sure that this file exist in `D:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib` (my installation path) but I am not sure why `ninja` can't link to it. Please any help..

Comment: Note on the leading `/` in the `/lib/double-conversion.lib`: this means that ninja searches exactly this **absolute** path, without prepending it with anything. Probably, something is wrong with the `vcpkg` package for ITK.

Comment: Found an issue in github https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/6975

Comment: I am fighting this same error today with ITK + vcpkg + Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to run cmake with the vcpkg cmake-tool like:

```
cmake CMakeLists.txt "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=D:\src\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake"
```

If I have understood this right this will held to add the correct foldernames. Just found this here: [using vcpkg with cmake](https://vcpkg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/installing-and-using-packages/)

Comment: I changed it as suggested by vcpkg targets suggested, and it get bit interesting because it is giving many `undefined external symbol` errors when configured with visual studio cmake but it compiles fine when I use the `cmake-gui` for configuring.

Answer (score 0):

Locate the "vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake" file. Search "VS_GLOBAL_VcpkgEnabled" and change property from false to true.